# How to compare character ignoring case in Freemarker?

Tags: liferay, freemarker

I need to compare strings case-insensitive in **Freemarker** template on *Liferay Portal*.
I tried with:

```
<#if nav_item.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("home")>
    <!-- if do -->
</#if>
```

But I get error:

```
Expected hash. nav_item.getName() evaluated instead to freemarker.template.SimpleScalar on line 39, column 46 in navigation.ftl.
```

As [indicated here](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_string_flags), I can use the common flag **Case insensitive** to not differentiate the lower and upper-case variation of the same letter. So I tried with:

```
<#if nav_item.getName()?matches("home", "i")>
```

But does not work! I get error.
Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`?matches("home", "i")` should work, so what error message do you get with it? Another solution is `nav_item.name?lower_case == "home"`. (BTW, you don't have to write `.getName()`, just write `.name`.)

Comment: Thank you so much @ddekany! I only changed `getName()` with `.name` and it works `<#if nav_item.name?matches("home", "i")>`

Comment: Um... it should work both `.name` and `.getName()`. Unless LifeRay uses some funny object wrapper, but I doubt that.